# I just installed a profiler into Tomcat 7 and now I'm getting BindException on shutdown

Tags: kill, profile, tomcat7, shutdown

So the HOWTO I just read says to add these JAVA_OPTS to the startup script:

```
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote=true
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=[place port number here]
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false
```

I did this and it works but Tomcat doesn't shut down and gives me

```
java.net.BindException: Address already in use
```

when I execute the shutdown script.

Comment: Solved: It's CATALINA_OPTS not JAVA_OPTS. The HOWTOs are wrong. Reference: http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/monitoring.html

Comment: Correct. Post that as an answer when you get a chance, and if you can remember, accept it once the question is old enough.

Comment: So let it be written, so let it be done. ;-)

Comment: The Tomcat server does not shutdown, because the JVM used to send the shutdown command will exit before sending this command to tomcat if shutdown JVM is using the same JMX port as Tomcat JVM.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved: It's CATALINA_OPTS not JAVA_OPTS. The HOWTOs are wrong. Reference: [Tomcat Docs Regarding Profiler](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/monitoring.html)